# Negative integers for no reason, cos, sin.

Tags: java, trigonometry

In java, I'm trying to operate on numbers with cos and sin, yet I keep getting negative variables, can anybody explain why?

This is my code:

```
double velocity_x=22*Math.sin(10);

double velocity_y=22*Math.cos(10);
```

They both respectively return velocity_x=-11.968464439566135

and velocity_y=-18.459573639681953

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you may not be doing anything wrong. sine and cosine return negative values sometimes. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The argument to `sin()` and `cos()` is in *radians*, not degrees. To convert, multiply by π/180:

```
double velocity_x = 22 * Math.sin(10 * Math.PI / 180);
```

Comment: I suggest changing 22, 10, and 180 to 22., 10., and 180.

Comment: @DouglasB.Staple: That's a good idea. Fortunately in this case, the presence of `Math.PI` will ensure that everything is done in double precision.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that, in this case it's just style/preference. Also, 236k? Holy smokes.